# How do I create embedded folders using Dropbox's Core Java API?

Tags: java, dropbox

I'm trying to create embedded folders using the createFolder() function call in Dropbox's Core Java API. (http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#createFolder(java.lang.String))

For example,

createFolder("/a") creates a folder with the name a.

If I want to create a folder "b" inside folder "a", how would I do so? When I call createFolder("/a/b"), it creates a folder b in the root directory, at the same level as folder a, which is not what I intended.

Comment: If true, this sounds like a bug, and we (Dropbox) will investigate and fix.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue. When I tried this with the [latest version of the Java Core SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/java), `createFolder("/a/b/c")` had the effect of creating a top-level folder called "a", a folder under it called "b", and a folder under that called "c". If you're still seeing this broken behavior, could you provide more details like what version of the library you're using and your exact code?

Answer (score 2):

Combine the createFolder with move to do what you intend.

> public DbxEntry move(String fromPath,
>              String toPath)
>                throws DbxException
>
> Move a file or folder from one path in Dropbox to another path in Dropbox.

So you create folders `a` and `b` on the same level. The  you move b into a using the move() method.